Is an HVAC Reducing Elbow a Thing?
We're installing a Rheem Hybrid (heat pump & electric) hot water heater. The space where the heater goes is very tight and I need to use elbow on the cold air discharge as I come out of the heater. The discharge is 8" and this results in the elbow protruding about a foot from the heater -- I've only got about 10" so it's time to get creative!
The discharge ducting will be short, so I could step down to 6" or even 5" ducting, but I need to make the first turn right at the heater.
So, what I think I need is either a reducing elbow or a very short straight reducer. Does such a beast exist? Google is finding me all sorts of irrelevant suggestions...

Reducers/expanders are common, depending on the size difference.  Reducing the discharge might not be allowed by the maker, it might be too much.

How short is short?

@crip659, reduction to 5” (along with a reduction in the length of the ductwork) is allowed within 10’ of the heater or 2’ of the discharge. The problem I’m having is finding a reducing elbow. Do you know if there is such a thing?

Maybe not a single piece reducing elbow, but reducing pieces that join elbows at either end.  Maybe explain/add picture of the problem.  If just drywall in the way, it might be easier to remove/adjust the drywall.  A cement ceiling would be more difficult, than drywall.  Wood joist can usually be be notched/cut a couple of inches.  A tin/sheet metal worker(found at HVAC/furnace installers) might be able to make a custom elbow, if extra space cannot be found.
